# Convert a 2D array to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, algorithm, pdo

My goal is to make a single database hit to generate a JSON array of objects with attributes that could be also be an array of objects, which could also have attributes that array of objects etc of an arbitrary (but known) depth.

I get a 2D array from my database using a PDO object.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($args);
$TwoDimArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $TwoDimArray;
```

So in my example, I have a Quiz, that can have questions, that can have answers. So a depth of 3. So assuming I have a 2D Array such as the table below, how would I make this JSON array using that data. (Note: other data has been removed for clarity sake, but questions and answers could have other attributes.)

[image: An example of a 2D array to the desired JSON object]

**Edit:** This is my attempt. It is horribly inefficient and not very abstract for the general case but this code will achieve the right answer for small data sets.

```
$data = ($database -> query($sql,$args)); // the result is $TwoDimArray
$quizes = array();
$quiz_id_list = array();
foreach($data as $quizkey => $quizvalue){
    if(!in_array($quizvalue["quiz_id"], $quiz_id_list)) {
        array_push($quiz_id_list, $quizvalue["quiz_id"]);
        $question_id_list = array();
        $questions = array();
        foreach ($data as $questionskey => $questionsvalue) {
            if ($quizvalue["quiz_id"] == $questionsvalue["quiz_id"] && !in_array($questionsvalue["question_id"], $question_id_list)) {
                $answers = array();
                array_push($question_id_list, $questionsvalue["question_id"]);
                foreach ($data as $answerskey => $answersvalue) {
                    $myanswer = array();
                    if ($questionsvalue["question_id"] == $answersvalue["question_id"]) {
                        $myanswer["answer_id"] = $answersvalue["answer_id"];
                        array_push($answers, $myanswer);

                    }
                }
                $myquestion = array();
                $myquestion["question_id"] = $questionsvalue["question_id"];
                $myquestion["answers"] = $answers;
                array_push($questions, $myquestion);

            }
        }
        $myquiz = array();
        $myquiz["quiz_id"] = $quizvalue["quiz_id"];
        $myquiz["questions"] = $questions;
        array_push($quizes, $myquiz);
    }

}
return json_encode($quizes);
```

The contents of $data looks like this:

```
array (
  0 =>array('quiz_id' => '1',   'question_id' => '1', 'answer_id' => '1',),
  1 =>array('quiz_id' => '1',   'question_id' => '1', 'answer_id' => '2',),
  ...
  5 =>array('quiz_id' => '1', 'question_id' => '2', 'answer_id' => '6',),
  6 =>array('quiz_id' => '1', 'question_id' => '2', 'answer_id' => '7',),
  ...
  22 =>array('quiz_id' => '2', 'question_id' => '6', 'answer_id' => '23',),
  23 =>array('quiz_id' => '2', 'question_id' => '6', 'answer_id' => '24',),
)
```

The result should return a json object that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "quiz_id": 1,
        "questions": [
            {"question_id":1, "answers": [{"answer_id":1}, {"answer_id":2}, {"answer_id":3},{"answer_id":4}]}, 
            {"question_id":2, "answers": [{"answer_id":5}, {"answer_id":6}, {"answer_id":7},{"answer_id":8}]}, 
            {"question_id":3, "answers": [{"answer_id":9}, {"answer_id":10}, {"answer_id":11},{"answer_id":12}]}
        ]
    },
    {
        "quiz_id": 2,
        "questions": [
            {"question_id":4, "answers": [{"answer_id":13}, {"answer_id":14}, {"answer_id":15},{"answer_id":16}]}, 
            {"question_id":5, "answers": [{"answer_id":17}, {"answer_id":18}, {"answer_id":19},{"answer_id":20}]}, 
            {"question_id":6, "answers": [{"answer_id":21}, {"answer_id":22}, {"answer_id":23},{"answer_id":24}]}
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Would need to know the contents of `$TwoDimArray;`

Comment: ![The json_encode of $TwoDimArray](http://imgur.com/drZpZ8H)

Comment: json_encode does convert the 2D array to json, but it does not convert it to the proper format of nested arrays. Only doing json_encode leaves lots of a redundant data.

Comment: Could you post the first few lines from `$data = var_export($TwoDimArray,true)`, just enough so I can see what is in `$TwoDimArray`

Comment: array (
   0 => 
   array (
  'quiz_id' => '1',
  'question_id' => '1',
  'answer_id' => '1',
   ),
   1 => 
   array (
  'quiz_id' => '1',
  'question_id' => '1',
  'answer_id' => '2',
   ),
   2 => 
   array (
  'quiz_id' => '1',
  'question_id' => '1',
  'answer_id' => '3',

Answer (score 0):

You say this is the contents of `$TwoDimArray`  There is not much that can be done with it.  I suspect there is something missing yet.

```
array ( 'quiz_id' => '1', 'question_id' => '1', 'answer_id' => '1', ), 
array ( 'quiz_id' => '1', 'question_id' => '1', 'answer_id' => '2', ), 
array ( 'quiz_id' => '1', 'question_id' => '1', 'answer_id' => '3', ),
```

This will get rid of your "redundant data":

```
foreach($TwoDimArray as $value){
  $quiz[$value['quiz_id']][$value['question_id']][$value['question_id']] =  1;
}
```

Comment: I add to my question. $data is my input and json_encode($quizes) returns the desired format (where "answers" is a list of answer_id's such that they share quiz_id and question_id that contained in the corresponding question object; and where "questions" is a list of question_id's such that they share quiz_id that contained in the corresponding quiz object. 

The php I added to my main post yields the right format but I don't think it will work for larger data sets. I hope this clears up everything.